# Wrong formatted `key_as_string` returned in date histogram

Tags: elasticsearch

`key_as_string`s are fine when I'm not using `"format": "YYYY-MM-DD"`:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "Filed" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "filing_date",
                "interval" : "day"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

returned

```
  ...
  {
    "key_as_string" : "2015-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key" : 1451433600000,
    "doc_count" : 12
  }, {
    "key_as_string" : "2015-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key" : 1451520000000,
    "doc_count" : 2
  }, {
    "key_as_string" : "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key" : 1451606400000,
    "doc_count" : 2
  }, ...
```

however, after I applied format, it returned

```
  ...
  {
    "key_as_string" : "2015-12-364",
    "key" : 1451433600000,
    "doc_count" : 12
  }, {
    "key_as_string" : "2015-12-365",
    "key" : 1451520000000,
    "doc_count" : 2
  }, {
    "key_as_string" : "2016-01-01",
    "key" : 1451606400000,
    "doc_count" : 2
  }, ...
```

which is clearly wrong.
Is this a bug or did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just a wrong date format and so you've mistakenly got the 3 digit day of year.  Assuming you were looking for a basic **four digit year, two digit month of year, and two digit day of month**, change the format string to:

```
"format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

note the lowercased d's.